# What does "as adj as there is" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *[The Markenmore Mystery](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/59818/59818-h/59818-h.htm#toc1)* (1922) by J. S. Fletcher, a rural man was talking to a detective about a conversation between two men:

> ‘You’ll be safe and snoring in your bed,’ he say, ‘at that time, no doubt.’ ‘Don’t you be too sure!’ say the little fellow. ‘I’m **as early a bird as there is** when I’m in the country!’

What does "as adj as there is" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you are the maximum of the adjective.

"He's as fast as there is" means no one is faster than he is. "She's as talented as there is" means she is the most talented person in the field.

"Early bird" means someone who likes to wake up early (and usually also go to sleep early) and functions well in the morning.

The passage means "Don't assume I'll be asleep at that time, because no one likes to wake up early more than I do."

Comment: This can maybe be better understood as short for "... as **any** there is."

Comment: @TypeIA And does this mean that "he is the earliest bird"?

Comment: @AhmedSamir Yes.